# Programmatically generating Solr (Lucene) query string

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have a complicated search form with lots of fields, which then gets generated into a Solr search string. I'm looking for advice how should this be done. (Like Prepared statements in SQL).

At the moment I'm thinking of something like this:

```
    QueryBuilder builder = new QueryBuilder(new WhitespaceAnalyzer());

    BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(builder.createBooleanQuery("field1", "foba*r"), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(builder.createBooleanQuery("field2", "fo bar*"), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            // ...
            .add(builder.createMinShouldMatchQuery("mmfield", "foo bar baz", 0.5f), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(new TermRangeQuery("datefield", new BytesRef("lower"), new BytesRef("upper"), true, true), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(builder.createBooleanQuery("", "-foo +bar"), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .build();

    System.out.println(query);
```

Which prints `field1:foba*r (field2:fo field2:bar*) ((mmfield:foo mmfield:bar mmfield:baz)~1) datefield:[lower TO upper] (-foo +bar)` which seems correct, however it feels stupid to pull in `QueryBuilder`, `BooleanQuery.Builder`, `WhitespaceAnalyzer` just to build a "simple" query.

If I leave out `QueryBuilder` then I would have to manually split the user supplied strings by space and create a boolean query out of the words, because I need to support wildcards, which PhraseQueries do not support as far as I know (For example. "foo ba*")

Answer (score 1):

You can use local parameter substitutions to send your information in separate variables and have the **prepared statements** kept Solr-side. Possibly with different request handler end-points for each statement.

See [my example for contact form search](https://gist.github.com/arafalov/5e04884e5aefaf46678c) that showcases complex query, multiple parameters and parameter substitution.

In terms of wildcards, you may want to look at [SurroundParser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-SurroundQueryParser), it apparently supports wildcards. Though, in general wildcards are not a good idea, computationally.